# reactjs issue show loading while dom render with more logic

Tags: reactjs, render, loading

I am facing issue with showing loading while DOM is rendering.
I know there are other related posts which focus on showing loading while data is being fetched, but mine is little different. 
I have logic in render method to render grid (with more data) that takes longer time. In this case, render function wont show loading since its still processing the logic.
Any help would be appreciated.

e.g.,

```
    class DataGrid extends React.Component {

  constructor(props, context) {
     this.state = {isLoading : false}
  }

  render(){

     //logic to render.
     .. 
     ..
     ..
     //takes long time
     return(
              <div>
                <Loader isLoading={this.state.isLoading} /> // This will not work since render is not complete
                <OtherComponent />
              </div>
     )
  }
}
```

Comment: To be honest, if it does take that much time, you probably should move that logic somewhere else

Answer (score 2):

Try taking your render logic out of the render function, something like this:

```
class DataGrid extends React.Component {

    constructor(props, context) {
        this.state = {isLoading : true}
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        //logic to render
        //once logic is done:
        this.setState({ isLoading: false })
    }

    render(){

        if (this.state.isLoading) {
            return <div>
                <Loader/>
            </div>
        }
        else return (
            <div>
                <OtherComponent />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not working as I receive data through componentWillReceiveProps and that is not calling componentWillMount() function. I tried componentWillUpdate() as well, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably two problems in your code.

1. In your constructor, you are not calling the `super()` method
2. If your logic takes time, put is inside a function that gets called on the render and because of async nature of JS, your return statement will get executed

```js
class DataGrid extends React.Component {

  constructor(props, context) {
     super(props, context);
     this.state = {isLoading : true}
  }
  logicFunc = ()=> {
    setTimeout(function() {
        this.setState({isLoading: false})     
        
    }.bind(this), 5000)
  }
  render(){

     this.logicFunc();
     
     return(
              <div>
                <Loader isLoading={this.state.isLoading} /> 
               
              </div>
     )
  }
}

class Loader extends React.Component {

  render() {
    if(this.props.isLoading) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>
    } else {
      return <div>Hello World</div>
    }
  }
  
}

ReactDOM.render(<DataGrid/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Hi Khatri,This will work as you have timeout as 5 sec. In case, if my render logic takes more than 5 secs then this will fail as setState will initiate another re-render

Comment: I am assuming that you have a logic that is triggered on the basis of isrendered state, or else it will be a much better idea to have your logic independent of render so that it is not executed everytime